# trigger click on element that has multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element:

```
  <a href="#" class='popup register'>Register</a>
```

and I want to trigger a clic action on this, how do I do this? I tried doing:

```
$('.popup .register').trigger('click');
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between the selectors.

```
$('.popup.register').trigger('click');
```

`.popup .register` means that trigger click event on the element with class `register` which is a child of element with class `popup`. So in your particular scenario this won't work as they are both on the same element.

#### [Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/NU3xf/)